# Why PowerShell profile not load function after creating exe

Tags: function, powershell, profile

I created a function within PowerShell profile and it was running successfully but whenever I converted my file from extension .ps1 to .exe and run .exe file, it will be show the error "The term 'Check-Expiry' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: _"converted my file from extension .ps1 to .exe "_  How are you doing this?  Do you mean you are simply renaming the file, or runing some sort of conversion app?

Comment: where is the exe file located? is it on the path?

Comment: Probably with PS2EXE or something of the likes, probably the function was not included in the code converted to binary hence the error.